# HTTPS login with Spring Security redirects to HTTP

Tags: spring, ssl, https, spring-security, tomcat6

I have a Spring web app, secured with Spring Security, running on EC2. In front of the EC2 instance is an Elastic Load Balancer with an SSL cert (https terminates at the load balancer ie. port 443 -> port 80), so from Tomcat's perspective, inbound requests are HTTP.

My login form submits to https, however the subsequent redirect goes to http (success or fail). The authentication was successful, and I can go back to https and I'm logged in.

My login configuration looks like so:

```
<security:form-login
    default-target-url="/home"
    login-page="/"
    login-processing-url="/processlogin"
    authentication-failure-url="/?login_error=1"/>
```

What do I need to change to make default-target-url and authentication-failure-url go to https?

- Tomcat 6
- Spring Security 3.0.x

Comment: I've setup an Apache rewrite in the mean time, but still curious if there's a way to do with within Spring Security config.

Comment: usually it is done at load balancer and configuration is called url-rewrite. This way load balancer makes sure that redirect stays at https.

Answer (score 31):

Your spring configuration should be agnostic to the used protocol. If you use something like "requires-channel", you'll run into problems sooner or later, especially if you want to deploy the same application to a development environment without https.

Instead, consider to configure your tomcat properly. You can do this with [RemoteIpValve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html). Depending on which headers the loadbalancer sends, your server.xml configuration needs to contain something like this:

```
<Valve
   className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
   internalProxies=".*"
   protocolHeader="X-Forwarded-Proto"
   httpsServerPort="443"
   />
```

Spring will determine the absolute redirect address based on the ServletRequest, so change the httpsServerPort if you are using something else than 443:

> The httpsServerPort is the port returned by
>   ServletRequest.getServerPort() when the protocolHeader indicates https
>   protocol

Comment: The actual code which loads http scheme from servlet request can be found from: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/util/UrlUtils.html


From there one can find out that, Spring actually collects http scheme from servlet request. So @marcelj solution is the perfect answer for this!

Answer (score 15):

If it is a Spring Boot application (I use currently the 2.0.0 release), the following configuration within the `application.properties` file should be enough:

```
server.tomcat.protocol-header=x-forwarded-proto
```

This worked for me on AWS with an load balancer at the front.

For Spring Boot < 2.0.0 it should also work (not tested)

Comment: This issue had been driving me crazy.  This suggestion worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I also had to add `server.use-forward-headers=true` https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html#howto-use-tomcat-behind-a-proxy-server

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with Spring Boot behind Google Kubernetes. Adding these two lines to application.properties did it for me

```
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol-header=x-forwarded-proto
```

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-security.html#howto-enable-https

Answer (score 3):

Solution was two fold

(1) application.yml

```
server:
  use-forward-headers: true
```

(2) in servers `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/oow.com-le-ssl.conf`

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443
```

(2.1) and enabled the apache module with

```
sudo a2enmod headers
```

Put it together with the help of [this](https://medium.com/@codebyamir/using-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-spring-boot-embedded-tomcat-f704da73e7c8) and [this](https://ycsoftware.net/invalid-command-requestheader-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-module/)

Comment: `server.use-forward-headers=true` is [deprecated](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#deprecations-in-spring-boot-22). Instead, use `server.forward-headers-strategy=native`, and **DO NOT** set it to `framework` unless you trust your reverse-proxy ;-).

Comment: We were faced with the error **"The information you're about to submit is not secure"** on chrome.  To solve the problem we added **server.forward-headers-strategy: native** to application.yml and added the following line to traefik in our docker compose **"traefik.frontend.headers.customResponseHeaders=X-Forwarded-Proto:https||X-Forwarded-Port:443"**

Answer (score 2):

One way I got this working is by adding the following config

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" >
    <form-login login-page="/login.jsf" authentication-failure-url="/login.jsf?login_error=t" always-use-default-target="true" default-target-url="xxxxx" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/logoutSuccess.jsf" />
    ...
</http>
```

Had to add `always-use-default-target="true"` and `default-target-url="https://...."`. Not the ideal way as you need to hard code the url in the config.

Answer (score 0):

I set requires-channel="any" on all intercept-urls. This allows it to still work in my dev environment where I don't use SSL.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/createUser" access="permitAll" requires-channel="any"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" requires-channel="any"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" requires-channel="any"/>
```

Then, create an apache virtual host that redirects all traffic to the HTTPS version.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.mywebsite.com
  Redirect permanent / https://www.mywebsite.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: After login, Spring will still send a Location header with a http address. The user won't notice, because your apache will instantly redirect him to https again, but it is still a serious security problem, because the browser will send the session cookies over an unsecure channel.

Comment: @marcelj - I just ran it through firebug and you're correct.  I'll try to figure out a better solution and revise my answer if I do.

Comment: @marcelj, Could you explain why this is a serious security risk or provide a reference that describes the risk?

Comment: @NathanWard If an attacker intercepts the HTTP request, she can serve a HTTP login form and retrieve the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing exactly same problem and till the time I get proper solution I am redirecting my requests from proxy server to tomcat server over AJP instead of HTTP.
Below is my apache configuration

```
ProxyPass /myproject ajp://localhost:8009/myproject
ProxyPassReverse /myproject ajp://localhost:8009/myproject
```

Answer (score 0):

use below lines of code in web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Login and Restricted Space URLs</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/j_security_check</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/loginpage.rose</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

it makes forced to use HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to REMOVE the property `server.use-forward-headers=true`.

This is my setup:

Digital Ocean LB --> Kubernetes cluster with Ingress --> Spring boot Application

Answer (score 0):

Tried everything mentioned above for my k8's to spring boot application, problem was k8 was secured and ssl was handled by SSL accelerator sitting in front of ingress. The application only received http requests and spring security also forwarded to http, which was never found. The solution that worked for me:

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-from: http://$http_host/
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-to: https://$http_host/$namespace/helloworld-service/