# In Spring Security 5.1.6, logout-success-url always redirects to HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: https, wildfly, logout, spring5

I have configured Spring security 5.1.6 in Wildfly16 application server.
For logout, i have done configuration as below;

When i'm using HTTP url, then no issues.  But when i'm using HTTPS URL , after LOGOUT link is clicked it is redirecting to the relative path configured in "logout-success-url" with protocol as HTTP instead of HTTPS.

I have already tried with "`<property name="redirectHttp10Compatible" value="false" />`" for InternalResourceViewResolver bean definition. But issue exists.

Also tried requires-channel as https.  But issue exists.
.

I dont want to hard code https URL in "logout-success-url".

Anything else we can try to fix this issue?

Comment: When you set requiresChannel to https, and then accessed the logout-success-url, what happened?

Comment: @NatFar....same result.  still login URL redirected as HTTP instead of https.  <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" requires-channel="https"/>

Comment: So far i'm adding a custom handler that extends "SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler".  Referring the customer handler in "success-handler-ref" is serving the purpose.  But still it would be easy if we have a solution that sets protocol from context in all relative path handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53751135/6796524) solve it on my side :

```
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol-header=x-forwarded-proto
```

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-security.html#howto-enable-https